# Unable to get Matcher.replaceAll to work properly

Tags: java, regex

I am having some weird issues with a pattern replace.

I have these two patterns:

```
private static final Pattern CODE_ANY = Pattern.compile("&[0-9a-fk-or]");
private static final Pattern CODE_BLACK = Pattern.compile(ChatColour.BLACK.toString());
```

ChatColour.BLACK.toString() returns "&0"

Next, I have this code:

```
public static String Strip(String message)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Matcher matcher = CODE_ANY.matcher(message);
        if (!matcher.matches())
            break;
        message = matcher.replaceAll("");
    }
    return message;
}
```

I have tried a couple different approaches, but nothing gets replaced.
The initial version just called each CODE_xxx pattern one after the other, but users were bypassing that by doubling up on ampersands.

I just do not understand why this isn't removing anything..
I know it is definitely getting called, as I have printed debug messages to the console to check that.

// Morten

Comment: Can you give an example of input (`message`) and what output you expect?

Comment: Input '&4test' should return 'test'

Comment: use `!matcher.find()` instead of `!matcher.matches()`

Comment: @jlordo You should make that an answer

Comment: using .find() appears to fix the issue, can someone tell me why?

Comment: @MortenNilsen `matches` tries to match the whole string whereas `find` tries to find a substring within the input that matches the pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) checks if the complete input string *matches* the pattern, whereas [`find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) checks if the pattern can be *found* somewhere in the input string. Therefor, I would rewrite your method as:

```
public static String strip(String message) // lowercase strip due to Java naming conventions
{
    Matcher matcher = CODE_ANY.matcher(message);
    if (matcher.find())
        message = matcher.replaceAll("");
    return message;
}
```

---

Just realized, this can be done with a one liner:

```
public static String strip(String message) {
    return message.replaceAll("&[0-9a-fk-or]", "");
}
```

Using the [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method you don't need a precompiled pattern, but you could extract the regex to a final field of type String.

Comment: @MortenNilsen: I agree, but I was too lazy to point that out ;)

Comment: I kept my while true, because I want to catch nested codes that people use to bypass the stripping .. Though, I suppose I should rewrite the regex instead..

Comment: Yet, I am not sure how to write a regex that turns "&&22a" into "a" and "&&&22 a" into "& a"

Comment: nah, that would turn "&aandy" into "y"

Comment: I wasn't looking close, deleted my comment as soon as I saw my mistake ;)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to limit the number of matched characters by the length of a previous back reference. You would need something like `"(&+)[0-9a-fk-or]{1,XX}"` where `XX` is the length of the back reference `\\1`